# Are Json values type specific

Tags: json

I'm trying to understand what is going on when I query data from a database and provide it to JSON and then push it to a GUI, in regards to what and when is converting to a string.

If I make a call to a database and provide this data as JSON to the front end, my JSON may look like

```
MyData{ [["Name": "Anna", "Age": 50],["Name": "Bob", "Age": 40 ]};
```

Visually it appears as if the value for `Name` is a string (as it's in quote marks) and the value for `Age` is an integer (as of no quote marks).

My 2 questions are

1. Is my understanding that the value for `Name` is a string and the value of `Age` is an integer or does JavaScript convert/cast behind the scenes?
2. How would I specify the *type* `DateTime`. According to [The "right" JSON date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286204/the-right-json-date-format) I actually just ensure the format is correct but ultimately it's a string.

Comment: That is not json. If it were json, the keys (Name, Age) would also have to be strings.

Comment: The json syntax is defined on [json.org](http://www.json.org/). Since json is used for many platforms that aren't javascript, target data type in your platform or runtime of choice is what is important, not what javascript would do (unless javascript *is* your target platform). `50` is in json syntax just a `number` though and can be floating point. If javascript has different internal types for integers and non-integers, then it will likely decode them to the right type automatically.

Comment: To answer your second question, you don't. You pick a type of the legal ones in json, which in this case would be either string or a number, and serialize it in that format, then you decode that value in the target. Usually it is serialized as a string containing all the bits and pieces to decode it correctly. It is definitely wrong to encode what would be legal *javascript* code, like something that calls the date constructor or something like that. That is *definitely* not json.

Comment: Google for "JSON spec".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is my understanding that the value for `Name` is a string and the value of `Age` is an integer...?

Almost. It's a *number*, which may or may not be an integer. For instance, `10.5` is a number, but not an integer.

> ...or does JavaScript convert/cast behind the scenes?

JavaScript and [JSON](http://json.org/) are different things. JSON defines that the number will be represented by a specific format of digits, `.` and possibly the `e` or `E` character. Whatever environment you're parsing the JSON in will map that number to an appropriate data type in its environment. In JavaScript's case, it's an IEEE-754 double-precision binary floating point number. So in that sense, JavaScript may cast/convert the number, if the JSON defines a number that can't be accurately represented in IEEE-754, such as `9007199254740999` (which becomes the number 9007199254741000 because IEEE-754 only has ~15 digits of decimal precision).

> How would I specify the type DateTime. According to The "right" JSON date format I actually just ensure the format is correct but ultimately it's a string.

JSON has a fixed number of types: object, array, string, number, boolean, `null`. You can't add your own. So what you do is encode any type meta-data you want into either the key or value, or use an object with separate properties for type and value, and enforce that agreement at both ends.

An example of doing this is the common format for encoding date/time values: `"/Date(1465198261547)/"`. As far as the JSON parser is concerned, that's just a string, but many projects use it as an indicator that it's actually a date, with the number in the parens being the number of milliseconds since The Epoch (Jan 1 1970 at midnight, GMT).

Two concepts related to this are a *replacer* and a *reviver*: When converting a native structure to JSON, the JSON serializer you're using may support a *replacer* which lets you replace a value during the serialization with another value. The JSON parser you're using may support a *reviver* that lets you handle the process in the other direction.

For example, if you were writing JavaScript code and wanted to preserve `Date`s across a JSON layer, you might do this when serializing to JSON:

```js
var obj = {
    foo: "bar",
    answer: 42,
    date: new Date()
};
var json = JSON.stringify(obj, function(key, value) {
    var rawValue = this[key];
    if (rawValue instanceof Date) {
        // It's a date, convert it to our special format
        return "/Date(" + rawValue.getTime() + ")/";
    }
    return value;
});
console.log(json);
```

That uses the "replacer" parameter of `JSON.stringify` to encode dates in the way I described earlier.

Then you might do this when parsing that JSON:

```js
var json = '{"foo":"bar","answer":42,"date":"/Date(1465199095286)/"}';
var rexIsDate = /^\/Date\((-?\d+)\)\/$/;
var obj = JSON.parse(json, function(key, value) {
    var match;
    if (typeof value == "string" && (match = rexIsDate.exec(value)) != null) {
        // It's a date, create a Date instance using the number
        return new Date(+match[1]);
    }
    return value;
});
console.log(obj);
```

That uses a "reviver" to detect keys in the special format and convert them back into `Date` instances.

Answer (score 0):

The specific format of a JSON string can be described by JSON Schema, as described [here](http://json-schema.org/); in particular, [date-time](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#anchor108) apparently is a type already defined in JSON Schema.